# changing the datagridview row height using rowtemplate but does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, height

I have a `DataGridView` with two columns member name and member image.

I want to increase the height of each row in the `DataGridView`.

I set the value for the property but height doesn't change, any other property also I have checked I mentioned below.

I have tried like this for changing  but any way it does not change the `DataGridView` row height...

```
var dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.RowTemplate.Height = 30;
```

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind data or set gridview datasource after setting  the `dgv.RowTemplate.Height` value, if already data loaded to grid rebind data ones setting above property.

Comment: I have set this property after binding thats why it does not change the rwo height.. many thanks..for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

> I want to increase the height of each row

At design time or programmatically?

If at design time:

In the properties for the DataGridView, find the RowTemplate property;

click the arrow on the right of RowTemplate, reveailng more details;

edit the Height property.

Answer (score 0):

Please load RowTemplate.Heigh before loading DataSource
ex:
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 32;
dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;